# How Can I style the colors in the AVPlayerViewController Tab Bar Menu on Apple TV?

Tags: uitabbar, tvos, tabbar, avplayerviewcontroller

The AVPlayerViewController Tab Bar Menu on Apple TV is the following :

[image]

It appears when you swipe down on the control.

I want to change its background color to orange. Also I want to change the color of strings to orange when it's focused.

I was able to achieve this in a TabBarViewController's tab bar with the following code :

```
[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor] }
                                                 forState:UIControlStateFocused];

 [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

How can I achieve this?